# how to get result based on float or int in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm trying to determine result based on the weather the output is `int` or `float`.

it just prints same number twice. Whether my `input` `odd` or `even` number.

```
number = int(input())
mod = number/2
if type(mod) == int():
    print(mod)
else:
    print(number)
```

Comment: edit your question with simple input and output in order to understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your type comparison is wrong.  Calling a type results in creating an instance of the type with a default value.  `int()` resolves to zero(`0`) and comparing a type to zero is always false.  Remove the parentheses to test for the type correctly.

```
>>> type(0) == int
True
>>> type(0.0) == float
True
```

However, the type of the result is fixed in this instance, and the type depends on the version of Python you are running.  The result of the division operator(`/`) changes.

In Python 3, division always returns `float`, so `type(mod)` in your example would always be `<type 'float'>`.

In Python 2, `3/2` (integer divided by integer) gives an `int` result (rounded toward negative infinity, e.g. `3/2==1` and `-3/2==-2`), so `type(mod)` in your example would always be `<type 'int'>`.  Python 2 can be made to work like Python 3 with `from __future__ import division`.

In both versions, you can force integer division with `//`.

### Examples

**Python 2.7**

```
>>> type(2/2)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(3/2)
<type 'int'>
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> type(2/2)
<type 'float'>
>>> type(3/2)
<type 'float'>
>>> type(2//2)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(3//2)
<type 'int'>
```

**Python 3.8**

```
>>> type(2/2)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(3/2)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(2//2)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(3//2)
<class 'int'>
```

**The Fix**

If you want to test for whole numbers, use the modulus operator (`%`) to compute a remainder.  Both `int` and `float` zero values are considered false:

```
>>> if 3 % 2:
...   print('odd')
...
odd
```

Comment: but if i run type(mod) it gives me 'float' if i input an odd number?

Comment: @AdetyaAggarwal Then you must be running Python 3, since `3/2` returns a `float`.  `2/2` also returns a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between int and int():

- int is the type
- int() is calling the type to construct an int; it will always return 0

So your trying to compare a type with 0, which doesn't make sense.

For type checking, use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance). Example: isinstance(3, int)

Answer (score 0):

> isinstance()

Try isinstance() to compare data types in python. Your Modified Code :

```
number = int(input())
mod = number/2
print(type(mod))
if isinstance(mod, int):
    print(mod)
else:
    print(number)
```

Do Have a Look.

Answer (score 0):

[In programming language generally we use typecast concept.First you need to understand the difference between the datatype and functions i.e **int and int()**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT6KL.png)

Number Type Conversion
Python converts numbers internally in an expression containing mixed types to a common type for evaluation. But sometimes, you need to coerce a number explicitly from one type to another to satisfy the requirements of an operator or function parameter.

Type int(x) to convert x to a plain integer.

Type long(x) to convert x to a long integer.

Type float(x) to convert x to a floating-point number.

Type complex(x) to convert x to a complex number with real part x and imaginary part zero.

Type complex(x, y) to convert x and y to a complex number with real part x and imaginary part y. x and y are numeric expressions